# Rewriting $|x-10|+|y-5|\leq 7$ so that absolute values disappear - Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

Equation 1: $|x-10|+|y-5|\leq 7$

I want to rewrite this equation into equations that do not have the absolute value.

$|A|\leq b$ can be written as

$A \leq b$

$A \geq -b$

I want to apply the same technique but there are two absolute values in the equation 1. I have:

$(x-10)+(y-5)\leq 7$
$(x-10)+(y-5)\geq -7$

Are the above equations correct? Also, do I miss some other equations other than the two above?

Comment: Have you tried using $\sqrt{z^2} = |z|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|x-10|+|y-5|\leq 7  $$can rewrite as :$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 (x-10)+(y-5) \leq 7&  x \geq 10 &  y \geq 5\\ 
 (x-10)-(y-5) \leq 7&  x \geq 10 &  y \leq 5 \\
 -(x-10)+(y-5) \leq 7&  x \leq 10 &  y \geq 5 \\
 -(x-10)-(y-5) \leq 7&  x \leq 10 &  y \leq 5 
\end{matrix}\right.$$ [image]